# Normalize histogram2d by bin area

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2D histogram that I generate with numpy:

```
H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y, x, weights=mass * (1.0 - pf),
                                   bins=(yrange,xrange))
```

Note that I'm currently weighing the bins with a function of mass (`mass` is a numpy array with the same dimensions as `x` and `y`). The bins are logarithmic (generated via `xrange = np.logspace(minX, maxX, 100)`).

However, I really want to weight the bins by the mass function but normalize them (i.e. divide) each by the area of the bin: e.g. - each bin has area `xrange[i] * yrange[i]`. However, since `xrange` and `yrange` don't have the same dimensions as `mass`, `x` and `y` ... I can't simply put the normalization in the `np.histogram2d` call.

How can I normalize the bin counts by the area in each log bin?

For reference, here's the plot (I've added x and y 1D histograms that I'll also need to normalize by the width of the bin, but once I figure out how to do it for 2D it should be analogous).

FYI - I generate the main (and axes-histograms) with matplotlib:

```
X,Y=np.meshgrid(xrange,yrange)
H = np.log10(H)
masked_array = np.ma.array(H, mask=np.isnan(H))  # mask out all nan, i.e. log10(0.0)
cax = (ax2dhist.pcolormesh(X,Y,masked_array, cmap=cmap, norm=LogNorm(vmin=1,vmax=8)))
```

[image: Phase diagram relating star particle metals to the fraction of primordial metals]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to pass `normed=True` to [`np.histogram2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html):

> **normed**: *bool, optional*
>
> If `False`, returns the number of samples in each bin. If `True`, returns the bin density `bin_count / sample_count / bin_area`.

---

If you wanted to compute the bin areas and do the normalization manually , the simplest way would probably be to use [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
x, y = np.random.rand(2, 1000)
xbin = np.logspace(-1, 0, 101)
ybin = np.logspace(-1, 0, 201)

# raw bin counts
counts, xe, ye = np.histogram2d(x, y, [xbin, ybin])

# size of each bin in x and y dimensions
dx = np.diff(xbin)
dy = np.diff(ybin)

# compute the area of each bin using broadcasting
area = dx[:,  None] * dy

# normalized counts
manual_norm = counts / area / x.shape[0]

# using normed=True
counts_norm, xe, ye = np.histogram2d(x, y, [xbin, ybin], normed=True)

print(np.allclose(manual_norm, counts_norm))
# True
```

Comment: Oh man... is it that simple?! I'll try and post the result. Thx.

Comment: Yep... I think that does it. Thanks for showing the broadcast method tho too... There's actually another variable I need to use in the normalization (volume of the entire simulation... so I can normalize to "per unit volume". So that tip will come in handy!

Comment: ![NewPlot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5614270/ZmassDiv1-PGFpltHistNormed-z_6.50.png)